# Database user table design, for specific scenario

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema-design, settings

I know this question has been asked and answered many times, and I've spent a decent amount of time reading through the following questions:

- [Database table structure for user settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974321/database-table-structure-for-user-settings)
- [How to handle a few dozen flags in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251924/how-to-handle-a-few-dozen-flags-in-a-database)
- [Storing flags in a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706379/storing-flags-in-a-db)
- [How many database table columns are too many?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464639/how-many-database-table-columns-are-too-many)
- [How many columns is too many columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184478/how-many-columns-is-too-many-columns)

The problem is that there seem to be a somewhat even distribution of supporters for a few classes of solutions:

- Stick user settings in a single table as long as it's normalized
- Split it into two tables that are 1 to 1, for example "users" and "user_settings"
- Generalize it with some sort of key-value system
- Stick setting flags in bitfield or other serialized form

So at the risk of asking a duplicate question, I'd like to describe my specific scenario, and hopefully get a more specific answer.

- Currently my site has a single user table in mysql, with around 10-15 columns(id, name, email, password...)
- I'd like to add a set of per-user settings for whether to send email alerts for different types of events (notify_if_user_follows_me, notify_if_user_messages_me, notify_when_friend_posts_new_stuff...)
- I anticipate that in the future I'd be infrequently adding one off per-user settings which are mostly 1 to 1 with users.

I'm leaning towards creating a second user_settings table and stick "non-essential" information such as email notification settings there, for the sake of keeping the main user table more readable, but is very curious to hear what expects have to say.

Comment: I would do what you're planning to do.

Comment: Cool, I'll just get by with the simple way, and migrate if a convincing reason manifests itself later on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that your dilemma is to vertically partition the user table or not. You may want to read **[this SO Q/A too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352324/when-we-need-to-use-1-to-1-relationship-in-database-design/6362543#6362543)**.

Answer (score 0):

i'm gonna cast my vote for adding two tables... (some sota key-value system)

it is preferable (to me) to add data instead of columns... so,

add a new table that links users to settings, then add a table for the settings...

these things: notify_if_user_follows_me, notify_if_user_messages_me, notify_when_friend_posts_new_stuff. would then become row insertions with an id, and you can reference them at any time and extend them as needed without changing the schema.